# How To Save Data For Bookmarks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsstring

I'm creating a very simple bookmarks menu for my app.  I just need to save 3 strings for each object.

I was thinking of using core data but I don't want this to be connected with my core database for various reasons.  Therefore what other easy options do I have?  NSUserDefaults or .plist?

I just need to save the 3 strings for each object then load them into a table view to be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend NSUserDefaults - is certainly easier. I tend to only use plist files for static data that I want to be editable as the developer, but from the application want it to be read-only (such as coordinates for objects on an embedded map image).

From your description, you would probably want to store an NSArray containing NSDictionary.

```
// Get the user defaults object
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


// Load your bookmarks (editable array)
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *bookmarksLoaded = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
if (bookmarksLoaded != nil) {
    [bookmarks initWithArray:bookmarksLoaded];
} else {
    [bookmarks init];
}

// Add a bookmark
NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"name"];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"description"];
[bookmark setValue:@"value" forKey:@"code"];
[bookmarks addObject:bookmark];

// Save your (updated) bookmarks
[userDefaults setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

// Memory cleanup
[bookmarks release];
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I go about setting this up?  Lets say i have a button on my tableview, that when selected, I want to be added to the bookmarks array.  I have 3 strings i want saved, `name`, `description`, and `code`.  Once saved, I need a way to load the array from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm getting crash at `[bookmarks addObject:bookmark];` that says `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object'`

Comment: I fixed your code you posted you forgot to `init` it.  But now I get this error when the method is called a second time `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[__NSArrayM initWithCapacity:]!'`

Comment: I call init on the bookmarks object within the if statement, 2 lines below it's allocation. You can't call init twice - which is what your code change has done.